# \G like vertical output in MySQL Workbench for show engine innodb status

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql5

`show engine innodb status;` is unusable in MySQL Workbench, as shown here:

```
=====================================120329 12:39:32 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT=====================================Per second averages calculated from the last 17 seconds-----------------BACKGROUND THREAD-----------------srv_master_thread loops: 192438...
```

However `show engine innodb status \G` is great on the mysql command line client.

Is there any `\G` equivalent on MySQL workbench or better way to get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you execute `show engine innodb status;`

- float the mouse over the Status field
- right click for a popup menu
- click 'Open Value in Viewer'
- When the viewer opens up, you can

  - Scroll through the Viewer
  - Click `Save` Button in the lower left corner to save to a Text File

Comment: Unnecessarily cumbersome way to do it. Better follow answer of Roman or Everaldo

Answer (score 11):

Or you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or choose 'Query → 'Execute Current Statement (Vertical output)'

Answer (score 6):

On MySQL Workbench 6 you can use Query -> Execute Current Statement (Vertical Text Output) like I explained in [MySQL Workbench Vertical Output](http://tecknow.com.br/mysql-workbench-vertical-output/) (Portuguese). You can also use keyboard shortcut Alt+Cmd+Enter (on Mac).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Run query with Alt+Cmd+Enter on Mac, or Ctrl+Alt+Enter on other systems and you see everything as with \G